# How do I properly build multiple pipelines via CDK and CodePipelines in the context of a monorepo?

Tags: deployment, devops, aws-cdk, cicd, aws-codepipeline

I've got a monorepo that's structured like this. All infra is CDK v2, and I'm trying to determine the best way to build pipelines in this context.

At this point, I've got two of them fully working, but they're quite slow as they're both triggered when an update is made from either the front or back-end.

```
my-monorepo/
├── node_modules
├── packages/
│   ├── infra/
│   │   ├── cdk.out
│   │   ├── stacks/
│   │   │   ├── ApiStack.ts
│   │   │   ├── AuthStack.ts
│   │   │   ├── DataStack.ts
│   │   │   ├── LambdaStack.ts
│   │   │   ├── BackendPipelineStack.ts
│   │   │   └── WebAppPipelineStack.ts
│   │   ├── cdk.json
│   │   └── Launcher.ts
│   ├── lib
│   ├── lambda
│   └── web/
│       └── react-vite
├── package.json
```

`Launcher.ts` looks like this:

```js
import { App } from "aws-cdk-lib";
import { WebAppPipelineStack } from "./stacks/WebAppPipelineStack";

//CDK App
const app = new App();

//CodePipelines
new BackendPipelineStack(app, "BackendPipelineStack");
new WebAppPipelineStack(app, "WebAppPipelineStack");

app.synth();
```

The `BackendPipelineStack` builds out API Gateway, Cognito, a Dynamo table, and a single Lambda that acts as the API.

The `WebApPipelineStack` simply builds a Vite React app and deploys it.

Both have different inputs, but essentially look the same, creating a self-mutating pipeline:

```js
const pipeline = new CodePipeline(this, "WebAppPipeline", {
    pipelineName: "PrototypeWebAppPipeline",
    publishAssetsInParallel: false,
    synth: new ShellStep("Synth", {
        input: pipelineBuildInput,
        primaryOutputDirectory: "packages/infra/cdk.out",
        commands: [
            "cd packages/infra",
            "npm ci",
            "npx cdk synth"
        ]
    })
});
```

I get basically what I want - two working pipelines. However, it feels pretty weird - any change pushed from any file in the monorepo triggers both pipelines and in total, takes about 15 minutes to run.

Is this bad practice? What would be a better, simpler design? I can't imagine this scaling well if I were to add more packages to the monorepo and things expand.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

CodePipeline executions are triggered by *any* change to the source repo and run *unconditionally* from start to finish.  As you experienced, these constraints can result in unnecessary builds, especially in a monorepo.  Codepipeline has no native way of selectively deploying only those elements that have changed.

Is there a "better, simpler design"?  That's a matter of opinion, but here are some options:

1. Dump the monorepo.
2. Run the backend and frontend deploys in parallel in a single pipeline.  Use the [Wave](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/api/v2/docs/aws-cdk-lib.pipelines.Wave.html) construct.   This is more complicated if your frontend depends on your backend for inputs.
3. Build a DIY conditional pipeline.  Connect your GitHub repo to a CodeBuild job.  Have CodeBuild look at the input artefact and determines which of your monorepo "packages" have changed.  If a package has changed, write the artefact to an S3 object (e.g. `frontend-build-me.zip`).  Change your pipelines' source from GitHub to that S3 object.  Your pipeline will now only run when `frontend-build-me.zip` changes in S3.  Presto, a conditional pipeline!
4. Consider [Amplify hosting](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amplify/latest/userguide/welcome.html) for your frontend CI/CD.  It supports features such as [branch deploys](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amplify/latest/userguide/pattern-based-feature-branch-deployments.html) out of the box. [@aws-cdk/aws-amplify-alpha](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/api/v2/docs/aws-amplify-alpha-readme.html) has the constructs you'd need.  You can migrate your frontend deploys to Amplify without changing your backend setup.

---

Here are some related AWS resources that I've found helpful:

- [CDK Docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/v2/guide/cdk_pipeline.html): Continuous integration and delivery (CI/CD) using CDK Pipelines
- [AWS Prescriptive Guidance](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/prescriptive-guidance/latest/patterns/set-up-a-ci-cd-pipeline-by-using-aws-codepipeline-and-aws-cdk.html): Set up a CI/CD pipeline by using AWS CodePipeline and AWS CDK
- [AWS DevOps Blog](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/devops/multi-branch-pipeline-management-and-infrastructure-deployment-using-aws-cdk-pipelines/): Multi-branch pipeline management and infrastructure deployment using AWS CDK Pipelines
- [AWS re:Invent 2021 (YouTube)](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=AF-pSRSGNks): Automating cross-account CI/CD pipelines
- [AWS Workshop Studio](https://catalog.us-east-1.prod.workshops.aws/workshops/484a7839-1887-43e8-a541-a8c014cd5b18/en-US/introduction): AWS Tools GitFlow Workshop

Comment: Excellent, thanks for weighing in. 1. This is the easiest solution. This is my first attempt at porting what I know to a monorepo, and so far I'm seeing mostly drawbacks and frustration. 2. I'll try this in the short-term. 3. This is very clever! It's maybe more engineering than I'd like though. 4. I'm trying to avoid Amplify altogether, as I'd rather not have the abstraction and keep it lower level.

Comment: Any chance you could point me to something that simply and concisely outlines setting up multiple environments (e.g. dev/stage/prod) now that you've seen what I'm doing? Isn't this what stages and waves were meant for? That's the last piece of the puzzle for me, really. Thanks!

Comment: @TsarBomba Glad to help.  I've added some links to the answer.  Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

You need to run a git diff command to see if either folder is affected by the current change and then run the action for that folder or exit.

I don't have any ready code for this but you can use any kind of `git` magic but in our case we have everything setup much larger scale with `pnpm nx print-affected`.

You can dump the monorepo, but then you'll have different problems.

Comment: I don't see how this would change the fact that the self-mutating pipelines would still both be triggered by any change, anywhere in the repo? How would a diff would solve the pipeline design issue for the monorepo, without some additional business logic like fedonev described? Not enough detail in your explanation, perhaps.